# How do you remove a broken theme from WordPress Admin (without FTP or Cpanel)

Tags: themes

Is it possible to remove a broken theme from WordPress using only the WordPress dashboard? i.e, without using cpanel or FTP?

Background: When you are doing customer support, its rare that you have access to the user's FTP or cpanel, but its pretty simple for them to set you up as a temporary user to troubleshoot their site.

Comment: Is this a single site or multi site? If single, maybe just delete it from the themes library? As admin you can do this through Appearance menu.

Comment: Ops, I completely forgot you could do that while writing my answer. :) Don't think I ever used admin to delete theme, usually just nuke folder via FTP.

Comment: In this case, appearance menu just has a message at the bottom that the theme is broken, but does not list the them or thumbnail in the grid of installed themes. WP 3.0.1

Comment: Does it show up in `Editor` so my answer applies?

Comment: @rarst: No. The user has run out of disk space, so this might be an isolated case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Appearance > Editor` to kill theme's header in `style.css`. Won't really remove it, but will prevent it from showing up as available in WP.

Answer (score 0):

When you not have enough rights on the files, then is the editor not possible.
You can use a database-tool; i use "[Adminer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminer/)" as plugin inside WordPress, install via automaticly installer and then you can edit inside the database. Search in the table _options, entries "template" and "stylesheet" and kill the values for this two entries. After this you can set a new theme normaly. Alternative you can set a new value for template and stylesheet.
[image]
See on the example screenshot for the values "greyfoto", this is the value for the theme.